# Oracle sql split string in chuncks

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a string with long multiple of 5. So the length can be: 5,10,15......
I would to split this string in chunks of 5 char to pass in the `IN` clausole:

```
String="00000111112222233333"
```

I would:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE  code IN ('00000','11111','22222','33333')
```

Is possible to do this in Sql?

Comment: I see you have "String=". Are you calling the SQL from another language (Java, etc.) or is that just to show what is the original String?

Comment: Yes, I am calling sql from Ibatis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select regexp_substr(s, '.{5}', 1, lvl) chnk 
from (select s, level lvl 
      from (select '00000111112222233333' s from dual) 
      connect by level <= length(s) / 5);
```

1. Use connect by to generate the desired number of rows
2. For each row find any 5 characters starting from the begining of the string and get Nth occurance.

Answer (score 1):

Using a hierarchical query to split the string and [`substr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm) to extract each chunk of data:

```
with data as (select '00000111112222233333' s from dual)

select substr(s, (level-1)*5+1, 5) chnk
  from data
  connect by level <= length(s)/5
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/37139